# How to change button alpha without affecting its text in Android

Tags: android, alpha, android-button, android-selector

I want to change alpha value of a button.

I know in xml I need to write this property:

```
android:alpha="0.7"
```

and its working.

But with changing alpha of button its text alpha is also getting changed.

Is there any way in Android to change alpha of a button without affecting its text, like iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background of the button to a semi-transparent image with 0.7 alpha, this will not affect the Text